# How to copy all outputs when all outputs cannot be shown due to size in R console?

Tags: r, dput

I have a data, named Grain, and this data is enormous (until 7849 rows).

After upload the excel file in R, I'd like to convert this data as code. So I used `dput(Grain)`.

```
Grain<- read_excel("Grain.xlsx", sheet=1)
dput(Grain)
```

However, due to enormous amounts, all output couldn't be shown in R console. As far as I know, the code should start with "`structure(list(`" but this output starts with values.

Could you let me know how to copy all output even thought all of them are not shown in console?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `?dput`. This function has a `file` argument. Give a filename and the output will be saved in this file. The particular default value `file = ""` is for output in the console.